# How to select Date one month prior to TODAY() from Js Datepicker in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[Select Date from JS Datapicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz6DA.jpg)

**Note**: Click on Above click to see the Screenshots.

Right Click is disabled on DatePicker, so i didn't get html code for datepicker as it is **JS Calendar**.

I want to select the date prior to today date. How can I do same using selenium.

How can I get the xpath for previous button on JS Calender & How can I select date? Since this is JS Calender therefore No HTML code for datepicker displayed.

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
                    <label>Date Engaged</label>
                    <input type="date" data-bind="momentDate: engageDate" required=""><span class="validationMessage" style="display: none;"></span>
                </div>
```

Comment: plz provide url on which you are working as it is not possible to answer your query as per the information provided

Comment: @rajNishKuMar Hi Thanks for reply. there iis sm privacy so cant share URl, but u can see screenhots of it. Click on above link

Comment: ok but in the screen shot no one is able to view the source code for the calendar so how any body can help

Comment: There is no source code for the date calendar. I saw properly. If were there, then I wud hv been  solved it. Whatever the socurce code is displayed in screnshots, is merely the code for that date field. I'm getting confued how to solve this query. @rajNishKuMar

Comment: which datpicker plugin you are using in your application

Comment: It's bug. However smone told me we can do same by data-bind option.
So can u plz tell me how to use Selenium to Find Elements By Data-bind options.